# Long Running Excel VBA Query Now Causing IE to Not Respond

Tags: vba

I have got a couple of tools which have worked for years, built and maintained in Excel. They open IE, log in to an industry database, copy back some info and then close again. There has been a recent update to Office and IE and now we`re having the frequent occurrence of IE locking up into a not-responding state as soon as it opens, particularly when using it multiple times.

The IE version was working on 11.0.56, but not on 11.0.65 - however rolling it back does not seem to have fixed the problem so it looks like the wider Office update may be impacting it.

There are a couple of different codes for the different tools, but they`re all experiencing the same issue.

This is the relevant bit of code, it looks like when it`s breaking it is immediately after IE has been opened. Any help greatly appreciated, as I say has been a reliable bit of code so strange it`s started to have such issues:

```
    Option Explicit

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim HTMLDOC As HTMLDocument
Dim strAddress As String
Dim strWarning As String
Dim booTOU As Boolean
Dim booSmart As Boolean
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim intCount2 As Integer
Dim intRowCount As Integer
Sub RegistryInfo()

On Error Resume Next

'Start
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'open IE

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

' Make IE visible

IE.Visible = False

'Go to the website

IE.navigate "https://www.electricityregistry.co.nz/bin_public/jadehttp.dll?MariaWebR"

'Wait for the page to load

Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IE.Busy = False
Loop

' set variables for easy access

Set HTMLDOC = IE.document
Set HTMLForm = HTMLDOC.forms(0)

'Look for username (tabindex : 652) and enter username / Look for password (tabindex : 654) and enter password

For intCount = 0 To HTMLForm.elements.Length - 1

    If HTMLForm.elements(intCount).TabIndex = 652 Then

        HTMLForm.elements(intCount).innerText = ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Value

    ElseIf HTMLForm.elements(intCount).TabIndex = 654 Then

        HTMLForm.elements(intCount).innerText = ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Value

    End If

Next

'Click ok on the web page

For intCount = 0 To HTMLForm.elements.Length - 1

    If HTMLForm.elements(intCount).TabIndex = 655 Then

        HTMLForm.elements(intCount).Click

        Exit For

    End If

Next
```

Comment: So  no error messages...just becomes non-responsive and hangs? Ah.... there will be no error messages... Get rid of  On Error Resume Next   and then re-run. Perhaps you have the On Error GoTo O in later code but if so, it should be used to close the On Error Resume Next as soon as possible.

Comment: Is there a reason why your variable declarations are not at local scope? I.e. why are they above the Sub RegistryInfo() and not below? But apart from that it runs fine for me on 11.0.9600.19036

Comment: Thanks @QHarr - I get an error message from IE saying "Internet Explorer has stopped working correctly..." which then closes - there is no error message from Excel itself even when the On Error Resume is commented out. Have also tried moving the Declarations in to the sub itself.

Comment: The code is still running fine from time to time for me, but it always reaches a point where this error happens now.

Comment: And you have ensured you don't have lots of other IE instances open?

Comment: Hi @QHarr - we managed to locate the issue - it was an updated version of the WebRoot extension which was causing the issue - have rolled it back and has fixed the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for sharing the actual problem and solution.

Comment: Was there any documentation you found that helped you identify this?

Comment: No sorry - just ended up being trial and error

Answer (score 1):

It was an updated version of the WebRoot extension which was causing the issue - have rolled it back and has fixed the issue.